# Unable to exclude .DS_store in rsync

Tags: macos, rsync

**My code**

```
rsync -exclude='.gitconfig' -exclude='*~' -exclude='.DS_Store' /Users/Masi/bin/ /Users/Masi/gitHub/dvorak/
```

I run it. It copies the .DS_Store to the destination folder although it should not.

This suggests me that the first exclusion do not work. It seems to be hard-coded in Git's default ignore -file to ignore .gitconfig.

**How can you avoid the coping of .DS_Store?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a dash on your "--exclude" flags.  Without it, I suspect rsync is thinking you're passing it a -e flag with the value "xclude=.DS_Store"; not at all what you want.

Answer (score 14):

Try the following. Place your list of items to exclude in a file

```
~/.rsync/exclude
```

One per line (wildcards acceptable).

Then use the appropriate option to read the exclusions from that file:

```
--exclude-from=~/.rsync/exclude
```

You may also wish to ask this on ServerFault, the sister site.

Comment: `--exclude-from=~/.rsync/exclude` didn't work for me, as the `~` didn't get expanded to my home directory, I had to provide the full path to it.